# Difference between Azure App Service Plans for Function Apps: Elastic Premium EP1 and Premium V2 P1v2

Tags: azure-functions

I have 15 Function Apps to be deployed do a given App Service Plan; however I cannot find which one would be more suited for this purpose: Elastic Premium EP1 or Premium V2 P1v2.

For each of those functions, I'd like to have 2 pre-warmed instances at all time, to avoid cold starts for a regular number of requests.

Both plans offer 210 total ACU and 3.5 GB memory.

One of the reasons I'm asking is because we have some underutilized "regular" App Service Plans (Premium V2) and it would be good to be able to deploy the Function Apps to those plans to optimize cost, but without loosing the Function Apps advantages (e.g. auto-scaling, same method of deployment, etc).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tried to build two azure functions, using `premium plan EP1` and `app service plan p1v2` respectively.  I found that there is no `Pre-Warmed Instances` option when using `App Service Plan P1v2`, so you can only use the `Premium EP1 Plan`.
[image]

[image]
If you really want to optimize cost, you can try to enable `Always on` in `App Service Plan P1v2`. If this cannot meet your needs, you can only use `premium plan EP1`.

[image]