# What the difference between Premium And Dedicated Plans for Azure Functions?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, price, dedicated

I'm trying to choose the plan that suits me best, but I can't figure out what the fundamental difference is between them. Both have autoscaling up to 100 entities, both include Virtual Network, private endpoints, always warm feature and allow you to run long jobs. Yes autoscaling is slightly different - but in both cases you have to configure it for yourself.
But the price is significantly different.

The premium plan says that you pay for the number of core seconds, but the Azure Pricing Calculator calculates the number of cores per month.

It seems to me that I don't understand something. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

It means, the pricing will be calculated in terms of consumption of Core units, memory across the instances in terms of seconds and invoice billing will come in terms of monthly usage as specified in demiliani's [article](https://demiliani.com/2020/12/02/moving-azure-functions-from-consumption-to-premium-plans/).

- In Premium Plan, VNet Integration is Regional and both Regional and Gateway allowed in Dedicated ASP.
- You will always have Pre-warmed Instances in Premium Plan and you have to configure App Service Plan to have the Pre-warmed Instances. Refer #[SO1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62747278/difference-between-azure-app-service-plans-for-function-apps-elastic-premium-ep)